# AddView on DialogFragment after orientation change not working

Tags: android, fragment, savestate, dialogfragment

I have an activity which needs to trigger 4 different DialogFragments in which i trigger an intent do get images from camera or gallery.
I can retain the fragment state and continue to observe the "onActivityResult" and send it to the dialogfragmentx but when they recreate and i try to show again the images that i got from the gallery, when i use "addView" on the linearlayout it does nothing.
Here is my code from the activity:

```
private DFrag_room frag_room;
private DFrag_terrace frag_terrace;
private DFrag_garden frag_garden;
private DFrag_parking frag_parking;

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (frag_room != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment_room", frag_room);
        }

        if (frag_terrace != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment_terrace", frag_terrace);
        }

        if (frag_garden != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment_garden", frag_garden);
        }

        if (frag_parking != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "fragment_parking", frag_parking);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        frag_room = (DFrag_room) fm.getFragment(inState, "fragment_room");
        frag_terrace = (DFrag_terrace) fm.getFragment(inState, "fragment_terrace");
        frag_garden = (DFrag_garden) fm.getFragment(inState, "fragment_garden");
        frag_parking = (DFrag_parking) fm.getFragment(inState, "fragment_parking");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (frag_room != null) {
            frag_room.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        if (frag_terrace != null) {
            frag_terrace.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        if (frag_garden != null) {
            frag_garden.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        if (frag_parking != null) {
            frag_parking.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

and the code from one of the dialogfragments (the procedure is the same on every one)

private LinearLayout layout_images;
    private ImageView img_add_image;

```
private File photoFile;
private ArrayList<Uri> images;

public DFrag_room() {
}

public interface DFrag_roomListener {
    void onFinishRoom();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dfrag_room, container);
    layout_images = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dfrag_room_imgs_layout);
    img_add_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dfrag_room_img_add_img);
    img_add_image.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        images = (ArrayList<Uri>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("images");
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            addImage(images.get(i));
        }
    }

    setRetainInstance(true);
    return view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // <-- must call this if you want to retain dialogFragment upon rotation
    outState.putSerializable("images", images);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    super.onDestroyView();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    switch (reqCode) {
        case CONF.REQ_PHOTO:
            if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if ((photoFile != null)) {
                    Uri img = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                    images.add(img);
                    addImage(img);
                }
            }
            break;

        case CONF.REQ_GALLERY:
            if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                images.add(data.getData());
                addImage(data.getData());
            }
            break;
    }

    super.onActivityResult(resCode, resCode, data);
}

public void addImage(Uri img_uri) {
    int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding_x_small);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(img_add_image.getWidth(), img_add_image.getHeight());
    params.setMargins(0, 0, margin, 0);

    RoundedImageView new_img = new RoundedImageView(getActivity());
    new_img.setLayoutParams(params);
    new_img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    new_img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_white_stroke);
    new_img.setCornerRadius((float) 6);
    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(img_uri).thumbnail(0.8f).into(new_img);
    layout_images.addView(new_img, 0);
}
```

When i get the image from the intent it works fine, but when i get it from the saved list of uris (onCreateView) it doesen't work

EDIT:
Sorry, the app doesen't crash, i don't see the image in my layout, it calls "addImage" but i don't see the images.

Comment: can you explain in details what do you mean by not working? e.g. the app crash? or no image is loaded, the layout looks empty? Also have you tried debugging? Did the function `addImage` being called?

Comment: check the log there will be message that why it is not available. most predictable issue can be of changing height or width of the container layout

Comment: I Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i tried to create an imageview with 0 width and 0 height beacusa I create it from the onCreate method where img_add_image.getWidth() is 0.